# a java multi thumb slider workable on nimbus look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jslider, nimbus

I needed a Multi Thumb Slider for java swing and i ended up using this
[Multi knob (thumb) JSlider in Swing](http://chetanmenge.blogspot.in/2010/05/multisliderdemo.html), after applying several tweaks to it as required by my application i made it working perfectly for the default or Metal LAF....

However I now need to change the applications Look and Feel to Nimbus, however this custom component is throwing an NPE in Nimbus.

The problem lies in its custom UI which calls super methods which use the basic UIManager properties which are not found in NImbus.

I have searched a lot on google and stumbled across [Multi thumb slider in Nimbus L&F](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2193920%5D%5B2%5D%20and%20%5BCustom%20Slider%20UI%20throws%20NPE%20with%20Nimbus) and [Custom Slider UI throws NPE with Nimbus](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6697886) but no workaround yet.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the JXMultiThumbSlider component from the SwingX project should work with Nimbus, generally SwingX supports Nimbus.

BTW, the easiest way to get the SwingX is to configure as a Maven dependency, because the website it not well-maintained (but the code is of high quality).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
        <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i tried using swingx but as u said, the website is terrible...
but since I have invested a lot of time in the multislider that I am originally using, I thought it would be nice if I could tweak on this one itself....
anyways i think i would have to google more on this stuff